# Django Rest Framework Flatten nested self-referential objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with nested self-referential objects.
I have field `responses` which is children the same Serializer like a parent.

It looks like tree but I'd like do this in one level. Is it possible in a simple way?
How can I solve this?

Model `Message`:

```
class Message(SoftDeletionModel):

    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='responses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ...
```

It's my serializer:

```
class RecursiveField(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        serializer = self.parent.parent.__class__(value, context=self.context)
        return serializer.data


class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    message_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    sender_user_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    sender_user_fullname = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    sender_user_email = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    read = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    attachments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    responses = RecursiveField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = [
            'message_id', 'sender_user_id', 'sender_user_fullname', 'subject', 'body', 'created_at', 'read', 'read_at', 'attachments', 'responses'
        ]
```

My present result looks like this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": 115,
            "sender_user_id": 1,
            "sender_user_fullname": "user1",
            "subject": "Temat",
            "body": "<p>Wiadomość</p>",
            "created_at": "2019-09-28T19:33:40.846822Z",
            "read": true,
            "read_at": "2019-09-28T19:35:58.889000Z",
            "attachments": {},
            "responses": [
                {
                    "message_id": 116,
                    "sender_user_id": 1,
                    "sender_user_fullname": "user1",
                    "subject": "Re: Temat",
                    "body": "<p>Odpowiedź</p>",
                    "created_at": "2019-09-28T19:35:52.485656Z",
                    "read": true,
                    "read_at": "2019-09-28T19:36:21.932000Z",
                    "attachments": {},
                    "responses": [
                        {
                            "message_id": 117,
                            "sender_user_id": 1,
                            "sender_user_fullname": "user1",
                            "subject": "Re: Re: Temat",
                            "body": "<p>Odpowiedź do odpowiedzi</p>",
                            "created_at": "2019-09-28T19:36:20.717966Z",
                            "read": true,
                            "read_at": "2019-09-28T19:36:20.714495Z",
                            "attachments": {},
                            "responses": [],
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like sth like this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": 115,
            "sender_user_id": 1,
            "sender_user_fullname": "user1",
            "subject": "Temat",
            "body": "<p>Wiadomość</p>",
            "created_at": "2019-09-28T19:33:40.846822Z",
            "read": true,
            "read_at": "2019-09-28T19:35:58.889000Z",
            "attachments": {},
            "responses": [
                {
                    "message_id": 116,
                    "sender_user_id": 1,
                    "sender_user_fullname": "user1",
                    "subject": "Re: Temat",
                    "body": "<p>Odpowiedź</p>",
                    "created_at": "2019-09-28T19:35:52.485656Z",
                    "read": true,
                    "read_at": "2019-09-28T19:36:21.932000Z",
                    "attachments": {},
                    "responses": []
                },
                {
                    "message_id": 117,
                    "sender_user_id": 1,
                    "sender_user_fullname": "user1",
                    "subject": "Re: Re: Temat",
                    "body": "<p>Odpowiedź do odpowiedzi</p>",
                    "created_at": "2019-09-28T19:36:20.717966Z",
                    "read": true,
                    "read_at": "2019-09-28T19:36:20.714495Z",
                    "attachments": {},
                    "responses": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: From your example, it's hard to tell: do you want `responses` in your serialized messages or not?

Comment: Sorry my fault, i edited my `results`. I want responses but only one level nesting.